# Shift Characters in a string in php

Tags: php

I have a string like this `ÎæèÂä@Ä`
What i wanted right shift every character and output `gstar b` 
How to do that in php. If it is circular shift it is preferable.

Comment: Well, I'd say you have to implement a loop iterating over the characters tp apply whatever function you want to and create a new string.

Comment: @arkascha What is function i should apply to shift a character

Comment: Well, use the normal conversion functions `ord()` and `chr()` to convert between a character and an integer, then you can apply plain math functions.

Comment: Thanks found the solution for ASCII. But for utf8 everything is different and cant apply my solution

Comment: Well, simple "shifting" cannot work when you have UTF encoding in mind, since in such encoding a single characters can have a different length in its storage format, from one to four bytes. You cannot shift that. Sorry.

Comment: @arkascha yaa. I understood that. thanks

Comment: One hint: maybe you should try to ask why you _really_ want to find out, not ask how you can get to work how you _think_ you can achieve what you want to find out :-) Keep your questions simple.

Comment: I suspect that the [`mb_string` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) are the way to go here. Specifically:[mb_substr  — Get part of string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

Comment: @Ryan Vincent yaa. i tried that before. but chr and ord only support ASCII and i couldn't find alternative

Comment: These are the 'multi_byte' versions and process UTF-8 correctly. You don't use `chr` and `ord` but extract parts of the UTF-8 string and re-arrange as required. It is a little tedious but should do what your want. imo, think of the UTF-8 string as an array of UTF-8 characters. The `mb_substr` function allows you to access the individual characters or a `slice` of the array. You can then build the output string accordingly. Put it in a function and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for ASCII. But won't work in utf8. So make sure when running this, charset not utf8

```
$str='ÎæèÂä@Ä';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
    echo chr((ord($str[$i]))>>1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
$string = "abc";
$shift = 1;
$shiftedString = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
{
    $ascii = ord($string[$i]);
    $shiftedChar = chr($ascii + $shift);

    $shiftedString .= $shiftedChar;
}

echo $shiftedString;
```

*ord()* converts char to int. Then you add your shift and converts from int to char with *chr()*, and append to a string.

Comment: Thanks. But I expecting actual shift operation like >> like in c++